# The named parameter 'fontSize' isn't defined. in flutter code

Tags: flutter

want to add 5 box containers display xs, s, m, l, xl sizes. but the code throwing errors. where should I correct this? please refer to the image here. I add a container to create those. I'm new to flutter and can anyone please help  [image: image of error] how can I fix this.

error >> The named parameter 'fontSize' isn't defined. in flutter code
error>> The named parameter 'fontWeight' isn't defined.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,

        ),
          body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
          child: Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.8,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/image23.png"),
              //fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,

            ),
          ),

        ),

          ),
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // Max Size
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        color: Colors.red.shade50,

                      ),
                      alignment: const Alignment (1,1),
                      height: 400,
                      width: 350,

                      child: Column(
                      children: const [
                        Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 40, 100, 40),
                              child: Text(
                       "Summer  Collections",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                   color: Color(0xff262626),
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    ),
    ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 270, 100),
                          child: Text(
                            "Sizes",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Color(0xff262626),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          ),
                        ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )

                    Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                height:49, width: 49,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(228, 228, 228, 1),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                                ),
                                child:const Center(
                                  child:Text("xs",
                                      fontSize:20,
                                      fontWeight:FontWeight.bold

                                  ),
                                ),
                            )

    ],




    )),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(230, 110, 0, 40),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text(
                          "Add to Cart ",
                        ),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.black,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20))),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15)),
                      ),
                    ),



               ]
                    ),

                  ],
                ),



    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way to use `TextStyle`. [reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html).

```
Text(
    'text',
     style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 20,
             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
     ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **TextStyle** :

```
Text(
   "your text here" , 
    style: TextStyle(
        fontsize: ,
        fontWeight: 
         ),
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `TextStyle` to change fontSize, color, fontWeight etc.

```dart
child: Text("xs", style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrote a wrong code,Try below code hope its helpful to you.

Refer **`Text Class`** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html)

Refer **`TextStyle`** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html)

```
 Center(
  child: Text(
    "xs",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Your Reslt Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Put the text styles in a TextStyle widget.

The problem here is pretty simple. The text widget does not have any attribute fontSize or font weight. Instead, it is the TextStyle widge.

#### This is how it works

```html
const Center(
  child: Text("xs",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: FontWight.bold
  
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the props of textStyle of Text widget, So first you have to give textstyle of Text widget, then set this.**

```
 Text(
"Helo world",
style: TextStyle(
  fontSize: 30,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
)),
```

Answer (score 0):

used this:-

```dart
Center(
  child: Text(
    "xs",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
),
```